# Perl DBD::Oracle Module installation

Tags: perl, oracle

Could someone guide me how to install the Perl `DBD::Oracle` module?

Here is what I have done so far:

- Platform: RHEL 5.8 64 bit
- Installed Perl DBI package
- Installed Oracle Instant client for Linux 64 bit (basi + sdk + sqlplus component for the instant client
- Have set the correct `$ORACLE_HOME` and `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH`
- Then when I do `perl Makefile.pl` it fails with the following error:

  ```
  I'm having trouble finding your Oracle version number... trying harder

  WARNING: I could not determine Oracle client version so I'll just
  default to version 8.0.0.0. Some features of DBD::Oracle may not work.
  Oracle version based logic in Makefile.PL may produce erroneous results.
  You can use "perl Makefile.PL -V X.Y.Z" to specify a your client version.

  Oracle version 8.0.0.0 (8.0)
  DBD::Oracle no longer supports Oracle client versions before 9.2
   Try a version before 1.25 for 9 and 1.18 for 8! at Makefile.PL line 271.
  ```
- The instant client version: 11.1.0
- The `DBD::Oracle` version is 1.44

If you have installed successfully with the Oracle instant client, then could you please let me know what am I missing?

Is it possible to install `DBD::Oracle` without using the Oracle instant client?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

- Install if missing ExtUtils-MakeMaker module (`sudo yum install perl-ExtUtils-MakeMaker`)
- Install Perl DBI module (`$ yum install perl-DBI`)
- Manually install below three RPMs for Oracle instant client (from [Instant Client Downloads for Linux x86-64](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/linuxx86-64soft-092277.html). The example is for v11.2.0.3.0-1: adapt the commands below to the actual version.)

  ```
  oracle-instantclient11.2-basic-11.2.0.3.0-1
  oracle-instantclient11.2-devel-11.2.0.3.0-1
  oracle-instantclient11.2-sqlplus-11.2.0.3.0-1
  ```

I am using 64 bit Linux box, so select your RPM filenames accordingly. Something like `sudo yum -y install oracle-instantclient*rpm` should do)

- set below variables:

  ```
  export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/oracle/11.2/client64/lib
  export ORACLE_HOME=/usr/lib/oracle/11.2/client64
  ```

  MacOS users will need:

  ```
  DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/oracle/11.2/client64/
  ```

  Also add `ORACLE_HOME` to your `PATH` variable.
- download **DBD::Oracle** from [CPAN](http://search.cpan.org/)
- untar the module and run below commands in given sequence:

  ```
  perl Makefile.PL
  make
  sudo make install
  ```

In case you get complaints about missing gcc you can (temporarily) install it and then remove it.

DONE !!!

Issues I had faced were due to the wrong `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. I had set it to `/usr/lib/oracle/11.2/client64` whereas the correct value is `/usr/lib/oracle/11.2/client64/lib`.

Certainly, this was a great learning for a newbie like me.

Comment: instead of downloading and untar the DBD::Oracle module I used `./cpan install DBD::Oracle`. At first I got the error for missing `oci.h` because I had not installed the `oracle-instantclient*-devel-*`. Helpful links: https://yum.oracle.com/getting-started.html, https://blogs.oracle.com/linux/oracle-instant-client-rpms-now-available-on-oracle-linux-yum-server-yumoraclecom

Answer (score 6):

you can also read my article [How to install DBD::Oracle](http://g14n.info/2013/07/how-to-install-dbdoracle) which contains all the steps required to install DBD::Oracle CPAN module, which is not a straightforward installation. The purpose is to reduce headache and turn it into a repeatable process.

Comment: @gerardw: thanks for report it, I just removed the last slash, maybe it happened since GitHub Pages upgraded to Jekyll3 and link format changes.
Actually I do not pretend to hype that link and
I do not gain money with my web site, I like to share my knowledge to give back to the community, and I am really convinced that the article
can help other people that struggled (like me :) trying to install DBD::Oracle.

Comment: Any chance you can update that doc for 12.x? 12.2 at least doen't include a .mk file, and the "demo" one is something that the build complains about. Why cant the CPAN module work for anything more recent than from 2014?

Comment: Hi @Otheus I am sorry but I am not using Oracle recently so I don't have an Oracle 12 to test it. Article was written for Oracle 11g, but, I don't understand the .mk file that you are referring since there is no mention in the article instructions. At which article's instruction step did you arrived? Which error did you get? Maybe I can help as well.

Comment: YEs, the instructions are short on helpful information. There is a `.mk` file which Oracle uses to help API compilers link in and get all the right headers. Unfortunately, they keep moving that file around in different directory structures. The latest is listed as `demo.mk`. Very (not so) obvious. :(  To get the DBD module to work, I needed only to cp the files in the directory containing `demo.mk` to its parent directory.

Comment: Prolly the best options is to report it here https://github.com/pythian/DBD-Oracle/issues

Answer (score 4):

Here's what I did on CentOS 7.2 using yum packages and CPAN. This assumes you're using Oracle version 12.1 but I would imagine most versions will work this way.

**Install Oracle Instant Client**

```
yum install oracle-instantclient12.1-basic-12.1.0.2.0-1 oracle-instantclient12.1-devel-12.1.0.2.0-1 oracle-instantclient12.1-sqlplus-12.1.0.2.0-1
```

**Copy demo make files**

The install expects the *.mk file to be in /usr/share/oracle/12.1/client64 but the yum package install puts them in /usr/share/oracle/12.1/client64/demo.

```
sudo cp /usr/share/oracle/12.1/client64/demo/* /usr/share/oracle/12.1/client64
```

**Modify .bashrc**

Add the following lines to your ~/.bashrc

```
export ORACLE_HOME=/usr/lib/oracle/12.1/client64
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/oracle/12.1/client64/lib
export PATH=$ORACLE_HOME:$PATH
```

Now source the file

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

**Update CPAN and DBI**

Update CPAN and DBI to the latest

```
cpan> install CPAN
cpan> reload cpan
cpan> install DBI
```

**Install DBD::Oracle**

```
cpan> install DBD::Oracle
```

Comment: Works for 12.2 64bit but there are warnings/errors. (Size_t conflicts with %d format, mainly.) Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

A little addition to slayedbylucifer answer. I had the same problem like mentioned in the question. I've done all the steps described by slayedbylucifer. But still I got the problem like mentioned [here](http://g14n.info/2013/07/how-to-install-dbdoracle/):

```
/usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/4.3/../../../../x86_64-suse-linux/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /opt/oracle/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/client_1/lib//libclntsh.so when searching for -lclntsh
/usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/4.3/../../../../x86_64-suse-linux/bin/ld: cannot find -lclntsh
```

So I created the following symbolic link:

```
ln -s /opt/oracle/app/oracle/product/<YOUR_ORACLE_VERSION>/client_1/lib/libclntsh.so $ORACLE_HOME/libclntsh.so*
```

After that step the error from above (cannot find -lclntsh) was fixed. The execution of the make command was without any errors.

The only problem I still have is that I don't understand why this symbolic link is necessary.