# Error using DBD::Oracle with instantclient 11.2

Tags: oracle, perl, cpan, instantclient

I Want to use perl module DBD::Oracle on Mac OS X 10.8.
I installed DBI through CPAN. 
Downloaded the Oracle instant client 11.2 (basic, sqlplus and jdk).
Extracted it to /usr/local/oracle.

```
$ ls /usr/local/oracle/instantclient_11_2/
BASIC_README        libnnz11.dylib      ojdbc6.jar
SQLPLUS_README      libocci.dylib.11.1  sdk
adrci           libociei.dylib      sqlplus
genezi          libocijdbc11.dylib  uidrvci
glogin.sql      libsqlplus.dylib    xstreams.jar
libclntsh.dylib     libsqlplusic.dylib
libclntsh.dylib.11.1    ojdbc5.jar
```

Then installed DBD::Oracle.
Now when I want to use DBD::Oracle it gives an error.

```
install_driver(Oracle) failed: Can't load '/Library/Perl/5.12/darwin-thread-multi- 
2level/auto/DBD/Oracle/Oracle.bundle' for module DBD::Oracle: 
dlopen(/Library/Perl/5.12/darwin-thread-multi-2level/auto/DBD/Oracle/Oracle.bundle, 1): 
Library not loaded: /ade/b/2649109290/oracle/rdbms/lib/libclntsh.dylib.11.1
Referenced from: /Library/Perl/5.12/darwin-thread-multi-  
2level/auto/DBD/Oracle/Oracle.bundle
Reason: image not found at /System/Library/Perl/5.12/darwin-thread-multi-    
2level/DynaLoader.pm line 204.
```

I have DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/oracle/instaclient_11_2
I have not a clue what I am doing wrong.

SOLVED:
I got the same error when trying to run sqlplus. I added my oracle client directory to my global PATH variable and it is working now.

Saw they did the same in this tutorial: http://www.janhellevik.no/?p=521

Comment: I don't know enough about Mac OS X's dynamic loader to answer your question, but that path (`/ade/b/2649109290/oracle/rdbms/lib/libclntsh.dylib.11.1`) looks really problematic.  That looks like the path that was used by the person at Oracle who built the Oracle client libraries, and it seems to still be encoded in the Oracle libraries.

Comment: Solved by adding my oracle client directory to my global PATH variable. Not the best solution but it's good enough for me :)

Answer (score 0):

Check this one out: [perl DBD::Oracle Module installtion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11407513/perl-dbdoracle-module-installtion/)

Above information is about Linux Environment. But you might get some clues on how to go about configuring `DBD::Oracle` on MAC OSX.

On linux, you need **"Basic, SQLPLUS and Devel"** binaries of the oracle instant client. Here is the directory listing on my Linux box:

```
# pwd
/usr/lib/oracle/11.2/client64/lib
# ls -l
total 185232
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root       368 Sep 17  2011 glogin.sql
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root        17 Jul  9  2012 libclntsh.so -> libclntsh.so.11.1
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  52761218 Sep 17  2011 libclntsh.so.11.1
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   7955322 Sep 17  2011 libnnz11.so
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root        15 Jul  9  2012 libocci.so -> libocci.so.11.1
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   1971762 Sep 17  2011 libocci.so.11.1
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 118408281 Sep 17  2011 libociei.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    164836 Sep 17  2011 libocijdbc11.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   1503303 Sep 17  2011 libsqlplusic.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   1477446 Sep 17  2011 libsqlplus.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   2095661 Sep 17  2011 ojdbc5.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   2714016 Sep 17  2011 ojdbc6.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    300666 Sep 17  2011 ottclasses.zip
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     66779 Sep 17  2011 xstreams.jar
```

and here is the list of oracle instant client RPMs that I installed:

```
# rpm -qa | grep -i oracle
oracle-instantclient11.2-basic-11.2.0.3.0-1
oracle-instantclient11.2-devel-11.2.0.3.0-1
oracle-instantclient11.2-sqlplus-11.2.0.3.0-1
```

Hope this helps.