# Oracle connection error with Perl

Tags: perl, dbi

Can't locate DBI.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /reports/ie/lib /reports/ie/lib/cpan/x86_64-linux-thread                       -multi /reports/ie/lib/cpan /usr/lib64/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi /usr/lib/perl                       5/site_perl/5.8.8 /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-mu                       lti /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.8 /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/lib64/perl5/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-                       thread-multi /usr/lib/perl5/5.8.8 .) at list_INLINE_XSite_WorkOrder.pl line 3.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at list_INLINE_XSite_WorkOrder.pl line 3.

Comment: did you install DBI with `cpan DBI` ?

Comment: Thanks, after installing the DBI module, it works now

Answer (score 1):

You will need to install DBI (the Perl generic database layer) plus some Oracle stuff. Please follow these instructions: [Perl DBD::Oracle Module installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11407513/perl-dbdoracle-module-installtion)