# DBD::Oracle installation causing error

Tags: linux, oracle, perl, module, cpan

I want to connect to an Oracle Database through Perl. For this, I'm trying to install DBD::Oracle from CPAN by using the following command:

```
[root@localhost Admin]# cpan DBD::Oracle
```

While running above command on my Linux terminal, I'm getting the following error:

```
[root@localhost Admin]# cpan DBD::Oracle
CPAN: Storable loaded ok (v2.45)
Going to read '/root/.cpan/Metadata'
  Database was generated on Thu, 27 Feb 2014 06:17:02 GMT
Running install for module 'DBD::Oracle'
CPAN: YAML loaded ok (v0.88)
Running make for P/PY/PYTHIAN/DBD-Oracle-1.70.tar.gz
CPAN: Digest::SHA loaded ok (v5.47)
CPAN: Compress::Zlib loaded ok (v2.063)
Checksum for /root/.cpan/sources/authors/id/P/PY/PYTHIAN/DBD-Oracle-1.70.tar.gz ok
DBD-Oracle-1.70/
DBD-Oracle-1.70/lib/
DBD-Oracle-1.70/lib/DBD/
DBD-Oracle-1.70/lib/DBD/Oracle.pm
DBD-Oracle-1.70/lib/DBD/Oracle/
DBD-Oracle-1.70/lib/DBD/Oracle/GetInfo.pm
DBD-Oracle-1.70/lib/DBD/Oracle/Troubleshooting/
DBD-Oracle-1.70/lib/DBD/Oracle/Troubleshooting/Win32.pod
DBD-Oracle-1.70/lib/DBD/Oracle/Troubleshooting/Vms.pod
DBD-Oracle-1.70/lib/DBD/Oracle/Troubleshooting/Hpux.pod
DBD-Oracle-1.70/lib/DBD/Oracle/Troubleshooting/Aix.pod
DBD-Oracle-1.70/lib/DBD/Oracle/Troubleshooting/Sun.pod
DBD-Oracle-1.70/lib/DBD/Oracle/Troubleshooting/Macos.pod
DBD-Oracle-1.70/lib/DBD/Oracle/Troubleshooting/Linux.pod
DBD-Oracle-1.70/lib/DBD/Oracle/Troubleshooting/Cygwin.pod
DBD-Oracle-1.70/lib/DBD/Oracle/Troubleshooting/Win64.pod
DBD-Oracle-1.70/lib/DBD/Oracle/Troubleshooting.pod
DBD-Oracle-1.70/lib/DBD/Oracle/Object.pm
DBD-Oracle-1.70/oci.def
DBD-Oracle-1.70/Makefile.PL
DBD-Oracle-1.70/MANIFEST
DBD-Oracle-1.70/ocitrace.h
DBD-Oracle-1.70/Changes
DBD-Oracle-1.70/LICENSE
DBD-Oracle-1.70/README.help.txt
DBD-Oracle-1.70/README.mkdn
DBD-Oracle-1.70/INSTALL
DBD-Oracle-1.70/Oracle.xs
DBD-Oracle-1.70/CONTRIBUTORS
DBD-Oracle-1.70/META.json
DBD-Oracle-1.70/oci8.c
DBD-Oracle-1.70/META.yml
DBD-Oracle-1.70/Oracle.h
DBD-Oracle-1.70/dbivport.h
DBD-Oracle-1.70/typemap
DBD-Oracle-1.70/t/
DBD-Oracle-1.70/t/23wide_db_al32utf8.t
DBD-Oracle-1.70/t/00versions.t
DBD-Oracle-1.70/t/22nchar_al32utf8.t
DBD-Oracle-1.70/t/31lob.t
DBD-Oracle-1.70/t/lib/
DBD-Oracle-1.70/t/lib/ExecuteArray.pm
DBD-Oracle-1.70/t/10general.t
DBD-Oracle-1.70/t/28array_bind.t
DBD-Oracle-1.70/t/26exe_array.t
DBD-Oracle-1.70/t/14threads.t
DBD-Oracle-1.70/t/rt74753-utf8-encoded.t
DBD-Oracle-1.70/t/23wide_db.t
DBD-Oracle-1.70/t/22nchar_utf8.t
DBD-Oracle-1.70/t/31lob_extended.t
DBD-Oracle-1.70/t/000-report-versions-tiny.t
DBD-Oracle-1.70/t/12impdata.t
DBD-Oracle-1.70/t/36lob_leak.t
DBD-Oracle-1.70/t/24implicit_utf8.t
DBD-Oracle-1.70/t/38taf.t
DBD-Oracle-1.70/t/21nchar.t
DBD-Oracle-1.70/t/70meta.t
DBD-Oracle-1.70/t/15nls.t
DBD-Oracle-1.70/t/39attr.t
DBD-Oracle-1.70/t/rt85886.t
DBD-Oracle-1.70/t/34pres_lobs.t
DBD-Oracle-1.70/t/56embbeded.t
DBD-Oracle-1.70/t/40ph_type.t
DBD-Oracle-1.70/t/55nested.t
DBD-Oracle-1.70/t/30long.t
DBD-Oracle-1.70/t/32xmltype.t
DBD-Oracle-1.70/t/58object.t
DBD-Oracle-1.70/t/50cursor.t
DBD-Oracle-1.70/t/80ora_charset.t
DBD-Oracle-1.70/t/51scroll.t
DBD-Oracle-1.70/t/01base.t
DBD-Oracle-1.70/t/20select.t
DBD-Oracle-1.70/t/nchar_test_lib.pl
DBD-Oracle-1.70/t/23wide_db_8bit.t
DBD-Oracle-1.70/t/60reauth.t
DBD-Oracle-1.70/t/rt13865.t
DBD-Oracle-1.70/t/25plsql.t
DBD-Oracle-1.70/examples/
DBD-Oracle-1.70/examples/japh
DBD-Oracle-1.70/examples/oradump.pl
DBD-Oracle-1.70/examples/ora_explain.pl
DBD-Oracle-1.70/examples/commit.pl
DBD-Oracle-1.70/examples/bind.pl
DBD-Oracle-1.70/examples/curref.pl
DBD-Oracle-1.70/examples/ex.pl
DBD-Oracle-1.70/examples/read_long_via_blob_read.pl
DBD-Oracle-1.70/examples/tabinfo.pl
DBD-Oracle-1.70/examples/proc.pl
DBD-Oracle-1.70/examples/sql
DBD-Oracle-1.70/examples/mktable.pl
DBD-Oracle-1.70/examples/inserting_longs.pl
DBD-Oracle-1.70/examples/README
DBD-Oracle-1.70/mkta.pl
DBD-Oracle-1.70/Todo
DBD-Oracle-1.70/dbdimp.h
DBD-Oracle-1.70/hints/
DBD-Oracle-1.70/hints/macos_syms.pl
DBD-Oracle-1.70/hints/macos_bundle.syms
DBD-Oracle-1.70/hints/macos_lib.syms
DBD-Oracle-1.70/hints/dgux.pl
DBD-Oracle-1.70/hints/svr4.pl
DBD-Oracle-1.70/dbdimp.c
DBD-Oracle-1.70/README
CPAN: File::Temp loaded ok (v0.22)

  CPAN.pm: Going to build P/PY/PYTHIAN/DBD-Oracle-1.70.tar.gz

Using DBI 1.609 (for perl 5.010001 on x86_64-linux-thread-multi) installed in /usr/lib64/perl5/auto/DBI/

Configuring DBD::Oracle for perl 5.010001 on linux (x86_64-linux-thread-multi)

Remember to actually *READ* the README file! Especially if you have any problems.

Trying to find an ORACLE_HOME
Your LD_LIBRARY_PATH env var is set to ''

      The ORACLE_HOME environment variable is not set and I couldn't guess it.
      It must be set to hold the path to an Oracle installation directory
      on this machine (or a machine with a compatible architecture).
      See the appropriate README file for your OS for more information.
      ABORTED!

Warning: No success on command[/usr/bin/perl Makefile.PL INSTALLDIRS=site]
  PYTHIAN/DBD-Oracle-1.70.tar.gz
  /usr/bin/perl Makefile.PL INSTALLDIRS=site -- NOT OK
Running make test
  Make had some problems, won't test
Running make install
  Make had some problems, won't install
[root@localhost Admin]#
```

Currently I'm using LINUX CentOS. On my machine I'm already using SQLDeveloper to connect to the Oracle database, but I don't know whether ORACLE_HOME is set or not because I didn't install that one.

Has anyone experienced the same problem before? Please tell me how to resolve this error .

Answer (score 2):

Refer these steps in given sequence.

- Install Perl DBI module
- install below 3 rpm for oracle instant client (from http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/linuxx86-64soft-092277.html)

  ```
  oracle-instantclient11.2-basic-11.2.0.3.0-1
  oracle-instantclient11.2-devel-11.2.0.3.0-1
  oracle-instantclient11.2-sqlplus-11.2.0.3.0-1
  ```

I am using 64 bit linux box, so choose your RPM accordingly.

- set below variables:

  ```
  LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/oracle/11.2/client64/lib
  ORACLE_HOME=/usr/lib/oracle/11.2/client64
  ```

  MacOS users will need:

  ```
  DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/oracle/11.2/client64/
  ```

  Also add `ORACLE_HOME` to your `PATH` variable.
- download **DBD::Oracle** from [CPAN](http://search.cpan.org/)
- untar the module and run below commands in given sequence:

  ```
  perl Makefile.PL
  make
  make install
  ```

  OR you can install the module using `cpan` command

DONE !!!

Comment: can you tell me how to install those rpm's??

Comment: my data base version is `11.2.0.1.0 `

Comment: my Data base is Oracle . Why we install `oracle-instantclient11.2-sqlplus-11.2.0.3.0-1` this rpm?? can you clarify me pls I'm confussing

Comment: I did what you tolled but still same error persisting me

Comment: Can you show the output AFTER setting the environment variables as shown?  Those should make a difference in the install, or at least a difference in the error messages.  Other suggestion buried above is to "install DBI"; you already have it but it's a few revs old.  Try to update that module first.  That will probably only affect DBD::Oracle's runtime performance, but it doesn't hurt to be up-to-date before trying to install DBD::Oracle.

Comment: @ jimtut There is no difference in error message after setting environment as shown on above

Comment: @slayedbylucifer this answer copied from ->http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11407513/perl-dbdoracle-module-installtion

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the info! I noticed that oracle-instantclient12.1-devel-12.1.0.2.0-1.x86_64.rpm installed into /usr. So adding a soft link like this helps me solved the problem.

sudo ln -s /usr/include/oracle/11.2/client64  $ORACLE_HOME/include

Answer (score 0):

Do not forget to have gcc installed before installing DBD:Oracle. It's also a pre-requisite