# DBD-Oracle-1.76 installation issue

Tags: linux, oracle, postgresql, perl, redhat

I am setting up a new server for `POSTGRESQL`, so we have to migrate from `ORACLE` to `POSTGRES` while installing `DBD-Oracle-1.76` package. However, we are getting error even though we have exported `ORACLE_BASE`, `ORACLE_HOME`, `LD_LIBRARY`, `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.

Here is what I have tried:

```
make

rm -f blib/arch/auto/DBD/Oracle/Oracle.so
gcc  -shared -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches -m64 -mtune=generic -Wl,-z,relro  Oracle.o dbdimp.o oci8.o  -o blib/arch/auto/DBD/Oracle/Oracle.so     \
   -L/optware/oracle/12.2.0.1/client_1/lib -lclntsh -ldl -lm -lpthread -lnsl -lirc -limf -lirc -lrt -laio -lresolv -lsvml       \
```

Here is the error:

> /bin/ld: cannot find -laio
>       collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
>       make: *** [blib/arch/auto/DBD/Oracle/Oracle.so] Error 1

Any ideas? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're on Redhat/Fedora/RHEL/CentOS then try this before `make`:

```
sudo yum install libaio-devel
```

If Ubuntu (or Debian?) try:

```
sudo apt install libaio-dev
```

...or `sudo apt-get install libaio libaio1 libaio-dev`

I also needed:

```
export ORACLE_HOME=/wherever/oracle18-instantclient/instantclient_18_5
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="$ORACLE_HOME:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/"
```

[Error while installing DBD::Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26200174/error-while-installing-dbdoracle) might be helpful.