# bugzilla on Centos7 issue

Tags: bugzilla

```
root@node167 ~/bugzilla $ sudo /var/www/html/bugzilla/checksetup.pl --check-modules
* This is Bugzilla 5.0.4 on perl 5.16.3
* Running on Linux 3.10.0 #1 SMP Tue Jan 25 12:49:12 MSK 2022
Checking perl modules...
Checking for               CGI.pm (v3.51)     not found 
Checking for           Digest-SHA (any)       ok found v5.85
Checking for             TimeDate (v2.23)     ok found v2.24
Checking for             DateTime (v0.75)     not found 
Checking for    DateTime-TimeZone (v1.64)     not found 
Checking for                  DBI (v1.614)    ok found v1.627 
Checking for     Template-Toolkit (v2.24)     not found 
Checking for         Email-Sender (v1.300011) not found 
Checking for           Email-MIME (v1.904)    not found 
Checking for                  URI (v1.55)     not found 
Checking for       List-MoreUtils (v0.32)     not found 
Checking for    Math-Random-ISAAC (v1.0.1)    not found 
Checking for              JSON-XS (v2.01)     not found 

Checking available perl DBD modules...
Checking for               DBD-Pg (v2.7.0)    not found 
Checking for            DBD-mysql (v4.001)    ok found v4.023 
Checking for           DBD-SQLite (v1.29)     not found 
Checking for           DBD-Oracle (v1.19)     not found 

The following Perl modules are optional:
Checking for                   GD (v1.20)     not found 
Checking for                Chart (v2.4.1)    not found 
Checking for          Template-GD (any)       not found 
Checking for           GDTextUtil (any)       not found 
Checking for              GDGraph (any)       not found 
Checking for           MIME-tools (v5.406)    not found 
Checking for          libwww-perl (any)       not found 
Checking for             XML-Twig (any)       not found 
Checking for          PatchReader (v0.9.6)    not found 
Checking for            perl-ldap (any)       not found 
Checking for          Authen-SASL (any)       not found 
Checking for         Net-SMTP-SSL (v1.01)     not found 
Checking for           RadiusPerl (any)       not found 
Checking for            SOAP-Lite (v0.712)    not found 
Checking for          XMLRPC-Lite (v0.712)    not found 
Checking for             JSON-RPC (any)       not found 
Checking for           Test-Taint (v1.06)     not found 
Checking for          HTML-Parser (v3.67)     not found 
Checking for        HTML-Scrubber (any)       not found 
Checking for               Encode (v2.21)     ok found v3.19 
Checking for        Encode-Detect (any)       not found 
Checking for          Email-Reply (any)       not found 
Checking for HTML-FormatText-WithLinks (v0.13)     not found 
Checking for          TheSchwartz (v1.07)     not found 
Checking for       Daemon-Generic (any)       not found 
Checking for             mod_perl (v1.999022) not found 
Checking for     Apache-SizeLimit (v0.96)     not found 
Checking for        File-MimeInfo (any)       not found 
Checking for           IO-stringy (any)       not found 
Checking for      Cache-Memcached (any)       not found 
Checking for  File-Copy-Recursive (any)       not found 
Checking for           File-Which (any)       not found 
Checking for              mod_env (any)       ok 
Checking for          mod_expires (any)       ok 
Checking for          mod_headers (any)       ok 
Checking for          mod_rewrite (any)       ok 
Checking for          mod_version (any)       ok 
***********************************************************************
* REQUIRED MODULES                                                    *
***********************************************************************
* Bugzilla requires you to install some Perl modules which are either *
* missing from your system, or the version on your system is too old. *
* See below for commands to install these modules.                    *
***********************************************************************
* OPTIONAL MODULES                                                    *
***********************************************************************
* Certain Perl modules are not required by Bugzilla, but by           *
* installing the latest version you gain access to additional         *
* features.                                                           *
*                                                                     *
* The optional modules you do not have installed are listed below,    *
* with the name of the feature they enable. Below that table are the  *
* commands to install each module.                                    *
***********************************************************************
*               MODULE NAME * ENABLES FEATURE(S)                      *
***********************************************************************
*                        GD * Graphical Reports, New Charts, Old Charts *
*                     Chart * New Charts, Old Charts                  *
*               Template-GD * Graphical Reports                       *
*                GDTextUtil * Graphical Reports                       *
*                   GDGraph * Graphical Reports                       *
*                MIME-tools * Move Bugs Between Installations         *
*               libwww-perl * Automatic Update Notifications          *
*                  XML-Twig * Move Bugs Between Installations, Automatic Update                 
*               PatchReader * Patch Viewer                            *
*                 perl-ldap * LDAP Authentication                     *
*               Authen-SASL * SMTP Authentication                     *
*              Net-SMTP-SSL * SSL Support for SMTP                    *
*                RadiusPerl * RADIUS Authentication                   *
*                 SOAP-Lite * XML-RPC Interface                       *
*               XMLRPC-Lite * XML-RPC Interface                       *
*                  JSON-RPC * JSON-RPC Interface, REST Interface      *
*                Test-Taint * JSON-RPC Interface, XML-RPC Interface, REST Interface *
*               HTML-Parser * More HTML in Product/Group Descriptions *
*             HTML-Scrubber * More HTML in Product/Group Descriptions *
*             Encode-Detect * Automatic charset detection for text attachments *
*               Email-Reply * Inbound Email                           *
* HTML-FormatText-WithLinks * Inbound Email                           *
*               TheSchwartz * Mail Queueing                           *
*            Daemon-Generic * Mail Queueing                           *
*                  mod_perl * mod_perl                                *
*          Apache-SizeLimit * mod_perl                                *
*             File-MimeInfo * Sniff MIME type of attachments          *
*                IO-stringy * Sniff MIME type of attachments          *
*           Cache-Memcached * Memcached Support                       *
*       File-Copy-Recursive * Documentation                           *
*                File-Which * Documentation                           *
***********************************************************************
COMMANDS TO INSTALL OPTIONAL MODULES:

             GD: /usr/bin/perl install-module.pl GD
          Chart: /usr/bin/perl install-module.pl Chart::Lines
    Template-GD: /usr/bin/perl install-module.pl Template::Plugin::GD::Image
     GDTextUtil: /usr/bin/perl install-module.pl GD::Text
        GDGraph: /usr/bin/perl install-module.pl GD::Graph
     MIME-tools: /usr/bin/perl install-module.pl MIME::Parser
    libwww-perl: /usr/bin/perl install-module.pl LWP::UserAgent
       XML-Twig: /usr/bin/perl install-module.pl XML::Twig
          PatchReader: /usr/bin/perl install-module.pl PatchReader
      perl-ldap: /usr/bin/perl install-module.pl Net::LDAP
    Authen-SASL: /usr/bin/perl install-module.pl Authen::SASL
   Net-SMTP-SSL: /usr/bin/perl install-module.pl Net::SMTP::SSL
     RadiusPerl: /usr/bin/perl install-module.pl Authen::Radius
      SOAP-Lite: /usr/bin/perl install-module.pl SOAP::Lite
    XMLRPC-Lite: /usr/bin/perl install-module.pl XMLRPC::Lite
       JSON-RPC: /usr/bin/perl install-module.pl JSON::RPC
     Test-Taint: /usr/bin/perl install-module.pl Test::Taint
    HTML-Parser: /usr/bin/perl install-module.pl HTML::Parser
  HTML-Scrubber: /usr/bin/perl install-module.pl HTML::Scrubber
  Encode-Detect: /usr/bin/perl install-module.pl Encode::Detect
    Email-Reply: /usr/bin/perl install-module.pl Email::Reply
HTML-FormatText-WithLinks: /usr/bin/perl install-module.pl         
COMMANDS TO INSTALL REQUIRED MODULES (You *must* run all these commands
and then re-run checksetup.pl):

    /usr/bin/perl install-module.pl CGI
    /usr/bin/perl install-module.pl DateTime
    /usr/bin/perl install-module.pl DateTime::TimeZone
    /usr/bin/perl install-module.pl Template
    /usr/bin/perl install-module.pl Email::Sender
    /usr/bin/perl install-module.pl Email::MIME
    /usr/bin/perl install-module.pl URI
    /usr/bin/perl install-module.pl List::MoreUtils
    /usr/bin/perl install-module.pl Math::Random::ISAAC
    /usr/bin/perl install-module.pl JSON::XS

To attempt an automatic install of every required and optional module
with one command, do:

  /usr/bin/perl install-module.pl --all
```

Installation aborted. Read the messages above.

I am on Centos7 trying to configure bugzilla 5.0.4, Getting Error when trying to check checksetup.pl on host, Not sure how can i installed required modules which are not found / how do i resolve this issue and move ahead in setting up bugzilla on my host

Please suggest how can i resolve this issue.

Comment: I am able to install few with following commeand :dnf install 'perl(CGI::Session)'
dnf install 'perl(DateTime::TimeZone)'
dnf install 'perl(Email::Sender)'
dnf install 'perl(DBD::Oracle)'

dnf install 'perl(Math::Random::ISAAC)'
dnf install 'perl(JSON::XS)'
dnf install 'perl(DBD::SQLite)'

dnf install 'perl(Model::TheSchwartz)'

But stuck with :-
Checking for          TheSchwartz (v1.07)     not found 
Checking for         Email-Sender (v1.300011) found v0.120002 
Checking for           DBD-Oracle (v1.19)     not found

Comment: I don't see relation with title of the question and the text stack added. Be specific and give the sequence of your steps performed, where you stuck/what options you have tried if any.

Answer (score 0):

To test that bugzilla is installed on or not on CentOS7 you try,  To search the repositories for a package type: `dnf search bugzilla` or else you can also try `rpm -q bugzilla`. When we you found dependent modules not found you need to search for the module on the internet and download it and install it. Or keep update the repo with the latest versions which your system says not found.

Please ref to to the [dnf doc](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/quick-docs/dnf/) and also [rpm commands](https://www.tecmint.com/20-practical-examples-of-rpm-commands-in-linux/).
To work on the installing the DBD-Oracle  [check the stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26200174/error-while-installing-dbdoracle).

Hope this helps you!