# DBD::Oracle installation requires oracle instant client to connect remote database

Tags: linux, oracle, perl

I have installed DBI module successfully, but while installing DBD::Oracle module i'm getting below error:

Multiple copies of Driver.xst found in: /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8/i386-linux-thread-multi/auto/DBI/ /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.8/i386-linux-thread-multi/auto/DBI/ at Makefile.PL line 39.
Using DBI 1.633 (for perl 5.008008 on i386-linux-thread-multi) installed in /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8/i386-linux-thread-multi/auto/DBI/

Configuring DBD::Oracle for perl 5.008008 on linux (i386-linux-thread-multi)

Remember to actually *READ* the README file! Especially if you have any problems.

Trying to find an ORACLE_HOME
Your LD_LIBRARY_PATH env var is set to ''

```
  The ORACLE_HOME environment variable is not set and I couldn't guess it.
  It must be set to hold the path to an Oracle installation directory
  on this machine (or a machine with a compatible architecture).
  See the appropriate README file for your OS for more information.
  ABORTED!
```

In google i found above module require ([already found this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22087477/dbdoracle-installation-causing-error))
oracle-instantclient11.2-basic-11.2.0.3.0-1
oracle-instantclient11.2-devel-11.2.0.3.0-1
oracle-instantclient11.2-sqlplus-11.2.0.3.0-1

But my question is, to connect remote database do i need to install oracle-instantclient?

Comment: Yes, you need to client libraries installed to connect to the server.

Comment: Doesn't this belong on SuperUser ?

Comment: as a sudo user i tried installing the module

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you need either the Oracle Instant Client or the full Oracle client.  The Instant Client is much simpler to install.  Once it is installed, you then set ORACLE_HOME to the directory of the instant client before starting the CPAN process to build DBD::Oracle

Beware that the DBD::Oracle tests will most likely fail, unless you have an Oracle server accessible with a suitable test schema for which you have appropriate credentials.  Again, you will need to set various environment variables so that the DBD::Oracle test framework knows where that schema is.  See the README file for DBD::Oracle for more details, but typically this involves setting the TWO_TASK and ORACLE_USERID variables.