# “Can't modify constant item in scalar assignment”? in AIX

Tags: html, perl

I'm getting this compilation error when running my code. Can anyone help what is wrong with this code. ?
Operating system is AIX

Error -

> *Can't modify constant item in scalar assignment at pet_logical_date.pl line 29, near "1}" Execution of
>   pet_logical_date.pl aborted due to compilation errors.*

```
Line 29 is - *print $cgi=>table({border=1});
```

CODE is -

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
#####################################################################################
$\="\n";
$ENV{ORACLE_HOME}='/oravl01/11.2.0.3';
$LD_LIBRARY_PATH='/oravl01/11.2.0.3/lib';

use Shell;
use DBI ;
use CGI ;

my $cgi = new CGI;
print $cgi->header;

print $cgi->start_html(-title=>'Basic CGI');

my $dsn = "DBI:Oracle:$db_inst";

$dbh = DBI->connect( 'dbi:Oracle:ABC',"DEF","IJK") or die "Database connection not made: $DBI::errstr";

my $sql = qq{SELECT logical_date,logical_date_type from logical_date where expiration_date is null };

my $sth = $dbh->prepare( $sql ) || die $dbh->errstr;

$sth->execute() || die $dbh->errstr;

print $cgi->table({border=1});

print "<tr align=center><th>$sth->{NAME}->[0]</th><th>$sth->{NAME}->[1]</th></tr>";

 while (@data = $sth->fetchrow_array()) {
   $Logical_Date_O = $data[0];
   $Logical_Date_B = $data[1];
   $Logical_Date_R = $data[2];

   print "<tr><td><font color='black'>$Logical_Date_O</font></td>
          <td>$Logical_Date_B</td><td>$Logical_Date_R</td></tr>\n";
}

print $cgi->end_table;
print $cgi->end_html;
```

Answer (score 1):

Line 29 should be like this:

```
print $cgi->table( { -border=>"1" } );
```

There is something else that, although is not the cause of the error can produce some unexpected behavior: your SQL query return a two fields recordset;

but inside the while loop you try to read a third field:

```
$Logical_Date_R = $data[2];
```

the variable Logical_Date_R is likely going to have a null value.

Comment: Thanks. The script is running fine from AIX m/c now. But when i'm calling this script from html (APACHE) i'm not getting any o/p in GUI. But able to get o/p from backend. Any clue ??

Comment: 1) check if the page you're getting from apache is an error page or the requested page that is not displaying any content (try to view the source code of the page);         
2) check the error log of apache (`/var/log/httpd/error_log`, `/var/log/apache2/error.log`, `/var/log/httpd-error.log`, ... something else).

Comment: I tested your code and I'm getting a normal html page with a visible table inside.
Try removing `$\="\n";` on line 3.

Comment: Below error is there in error.log file.

install_driver(Oracle) failed: Can't load '/apache/perl/lib/site_perl/5.10.0/aix-thread-multi-64all/auto/DBD/Oracle/Oracle.so' for module DBD::Oracle: Could not load module 
\tDependent module libclntsh.so could not be loaded., 
 Could not load module libclntsh.so.

Comment: Maybe you could takea look a this guide [link](http://g14n.info/2013/07/how-to-install-dbdoracle/) or at this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11407513/perl-dbdoracle-module-installation). It seems that you have some problem with DBD::Oracle. We may be going off topic regarding the question subject, consider opening a new one.

Answer (score 0):

`print $cgi=>table({border=1});` is trying to assign `border=1`.  I think you meant `border => 1` (changing the assignment operator, `=`, to the fat comma, `=>`).

Comment: Thanks for the help. It's moved. But  getting below error now :- Undefined subroutine &main::table called at  line 29.

Comment: @manavsharma - in your code it's `$cgi->table` but in your "Line 29" above your code it's `$cgi=>table` - if you changed this part from `->` to `=>`, then that would give you a problem.  The full line should be as the other answer, `$cgi->table({ -border => 1 })` (not sure if the `-` is required in front of `border` - Roger is probably correct, I just don't use CGI.)